# table with images of same relative size in github markdown

Tags: css, github, markdown

In GitHub's markdown, I have a table with one row and two columns, each containing an `<img/>`. Without any `width` specification, the right of the two images is far larger than the left.

[image]

I would like to make sure the two images have the same width, but I don't want to specify the absolute size to avoid display issues on small screens.
I'd love

```markdown
<img src="img1.png" width="45%"/> | <img src="img2.png" width="45%"/>                                                          
:----:|:----:|
```

but apparently the `45%` is now relative to the width of the *column*, not the page.

[image: n]

Any hints?

Comment: Any code samples?

Comment: If not what I would do is enclose both images in <div> at 50% width each. If you use <table>, the table might spillover in a smaller screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown extends HTML, so one can simply use HTML tables:

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td width="50%"></td>
  <td width="50%"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```